# How to turn bad experiences into good explanation?

Tags: interviewing, professionalism, career-development, work-experience, feedback

I would like to ask how can I explain in a professional way these experience to potential HR :

1. bachelor's degree internship : it a was a startup in healthcare, never coded during university and had in 3 months to deliver a complex webapp in Angular with a mentor that would follow 5 peoples, so she had not so much time for me.

Needless to say,it's has been a bath of blood because I was not cut out for web app coding in Angular JS.
My relator was in affair with this startup,he blackmailed me that if I would not create a prototype that couldn't be sold, he would lower my bachelor degree GPA.

This startup used rolling internship as my thesis professor would send fresh students.

My performance was really bad, I have to admit.
Angular JS is a technology which I was not and will never be good at it,

I felt worthless because I gave hell to create a barely working prototype, working until 2 am, my mental health got worse in that dark period.

I discovered later that they sold my work for the price of an house,the blackmail was fake, that they were trying to make me postpone the bachelor's degree and work for them free for another half year.
I didn't tell the university all these bad behavior because I was afraid of backslash on my future,

Now, this CEO and relator managed to enter in huge healthcare companies which I would like to work with, I'm afraid that this experience could hurt my dream of working in these companies.

How can I defend myself or explain this bad experience to potential HR if they would come to know?

Should I tell the real truth to an HR of these peoples which took advantage of me and other students ?

This has been lot of years ago and until now I've worked in big companies :)

Comment: If is in the remote past, as you seem to indicate, why bring it up at all?

Comment: I'm Afraid that what happened in thesis could backslash me, even after a lot if years. The two guys I mentioned work in the companies I would want to apply. I'm asking what if these two guys bring it up, what should I say to a potential HR?

Comment: HR won't care what happened years ago. Especially at such a junior stage of a career. If someone brings it up, don't use terms like "blackmail". Just keep it simple and relative to things you could control.

Comment: @gnat Nice way to demonstrate that this has been asked many times in different ways.  (3 dupes deep!)

Comment: So, you did extra work, and you feel like it wasn't that good, but it was good enough to sell?  It was a bad experience for you, but it doesn't sound like something that should count against you in any way.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere in some countries, internship is considered a graded course that you take for your bachelor. Those courses have a supervisor (sometimes called a relator) from the university who gets in touch with whomever is supervising you at the company you're interning at and, after receiving their report / feedback about you, you get a grade for that course and it counts towards your GPA. So in this case, it seems a huge case of collusion between the startup and the university

Comment: Whoa, they placed totally unrealistic expectations on you, and you believed them, even fulfilled them. Hope you see that in retrospect.

Comment: Relator is the thesis professor,  when you do a thesis,  you're assigned a professor that acts as a tutor, which is called relator

Answer (score 5):

#### No one cares how well you did or didn't do in your internship at a dodgy company during undergraduate studies.

If they ask what you learned say, "Patience and a better ability to discern workplace issues."

Comment: +1: nobody cares. Particularly in this case which seems like a mandatory internship to get your degree. If it is not relevant to the position at hand, you shouldn't even mention it in a resume - I interned for 6 months in a hospital (compulsory for my degree) and I don't mention it in my resume, only in my full CV. If someone asks me about that, I say "I learned that I don't want to work in a hospital"